NSWindow with SwiftUI content has zero frame on macOS 15
As title says. I create a window as such:
onboardWindow?.setFrame(.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400), display: false)
Then, when it's time to show:
let contentView = WelcomeView()
let hostingVC = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
onboardWindow?.contentViewController = hostingVC

Before I set the contentViewController the frame is correct (the arbitrary values I set in the initialiser):
(0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 400.0)
After setting the contentViewController:
(0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Minified WelcomeView:
struct WelcomeView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        Text("Hello, SO")
    }
    .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
    .background(Color.main)
  }
}

The window is displayed correctly (in terms of size and look), albeit at random position, because I cannot position a zero-sized frame.
Anyone came across this issue? This worked nicely on macOS 14 and lower. It broke on macOS 15 (Sequoia).

A hacky workaround: When I use contentView instead of contentViewController then it respects the initial frame I give it (600x400) but that requires me to duplicately set the size values both for the window initializer and the .frame() modifier on the SwiftUI view. I am going with this for now but I don't like it. Is there a way to define the size only in one place (preferrably in SwiftUI)?

I put a gist together where you can see an example that may work for you. The App starts with a ContentView, which launches the WelcomeView based on a button press. The gist is here.
The project is a newly-created SwiftUI project targeting only macOS, I only included the main Swift files. I experimented with getting the main ContentView created by the project to be constrained to a specific size, and found that this approach doesn't work in that case. If this solution doesn't help you, you may want to post a minimal (but complete) setup where the problem exists.

I have an AppKit setup. I have been maintaining the app for a while now. So i need this to work in AppKit. The minimal setup is described above. Just start a new AppKit app.
